# How to stop returning the index and column name when using loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I have a tkinter program that connects to a CSV file. I am trying to insert certain values from the CSV file into text boxes in tkinter. I am selecting the values using loc slicing.

The problem I am running into is that my slicing returns the column name and index in addition to the value I want. Because of this, I cannot insert the correct value into my tkinter text box. Can someone help me remove the column name and index from my results?

Code:

```
ID = Entry6.get()
follow_up_DF = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
name = follow_up_DF.loc[follow_up_DF["Email ID"] == int(ID),["Name"]]
subject=Text(home, height=1)
subject.insert(1.0,(name))
subject.place(x=0, y=400)
```

Comment: Try doing `name = follow_up_DF.loc[follow_up_DF["Email ID"] == int(ID),["Name"]].value` to simply get the value of the target location.

Comment: [Serialization / IO / conversion](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#serialization-io-conversion).  `.values` - [Attributes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#attributes). `to_list()` - [Conversion](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#conversion).

Comment: I added "values" to the end of the code and am now getting the correct value returned, however, it is surrounded by brackets. The value returned looks like this [['XXXX']]. Is there any way to only return the string of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making name equal to this:

```
name = follow_up_DF.loc[follow_up_DF["Email ID"] == int(ID),["Name"]].value[0][0]
```

.value should return just the item from the row, not its index and column name.

Comment: When I used this I got the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: try subscripting .values like this --> follow_up_DF.loc[follow_up_DF["Email ID"] == int(ID),["Name"]].values[0]

Comment: Thank you - This works in getting rid of one set of brackets, but not the second set or the quotes. Right now I am getting a result like this ['XXXX']

Comment: do it again then, ie follow_up_DF.loc[follow_up_DF["Email ID"] == int(ID),["Name"]].values[0][0]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you for your patience, Python beginner here just getting started :)

Comment: No problem, I updated the answer so it was accurate for you or anyone else to come back to. Make sure to accept the answer so others can find their answer faster.